# Defrag/decrease heap size on pre honeycomb

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

I developed an app that on startup parses some pretty big amounts of JSON which causes the heap to grow close to its limit. A little later the app is loading several bitmaps. On Honeycomb and above devices, which seem to be using the same memory region for bitmap allocations as well as Java object allocations, this isn't causing any issues as the memory needed for JSON parsing has been freed by then. However on pre-Honeycomb devices it causes OutOfMemoryErrors

As the heap size never goes down dalvik seems to not be able to grow the memory reserved for external allocations (e.g. bitmaps).

This is one example log output for a crash

```
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 601K, 81% free 5504K/27591K, external 4809K/5561K, paused 58ms
586224-byte external allocation too large for this process.
```

As you can see there is plenty of memory available on the heap but not much for external allocation.

Is there a way I can force dalvik to defrag and shrink the heap? Or can I force bitmap allocations to happen on the heap instead of memory reserved for external allocations? Or is there any other approach to this problem I'm missing out on?

** UPDATE **

Here is more log output (the specific device doesn't log dalvik-heap messages):

On startup when the JSON gets parsed the dalvik heap grows:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 800K, 19% free 12717K/15687K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 871K, 19% free 13857K/16903K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1106K, 19% free 14766K/18055K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 3ms+5ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 818K, 16% free 15946K/18951K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 3ms+6ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 825K, 15% free 17151K/20167K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+6ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 830K, 15% free 18356K/21383K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 814K, 14% free 19519K/22535K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+6ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 823K, 13% free 20720K/23751K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 814K, 13% free 21873K/24903K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 3ms+6ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 813K, 12% free 23016K/26055K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 1771K, 15% free 23205K/27207K, external 2637K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
```

After that's done most of the heap gets freed again successfully:

```
GC_EXPLICIT freed 19207K, 83% free 4735K/27207K, external 2736K/2773K, paused 140ms
```

At this point I have 20 MB free Dalvik heap space and start allocating bitmaps a little later:

```
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 254K, 83% free 4814K/27207K, external 2771K/2773K, paused 47ms
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 721K, 83% free 4880K/27207K, external 3881K/4131K, paused 50ms
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 235K, 83% free 4870K/27207K, external 5398K/5561K, paused 62ms
```

Total device limit seems to be 32 MB the dalvik heap takes 27 MB of those and never goes down so I run out of external memory space to alloc bitmaps.

Comment: Can you try this test: before you start with the JSON parse, allocate a continuous chunk of 1-2MB in the dalvik heap (something like byte[]). When you finish your JSON parse and before you start the bitmaps, free this chunk by nulling it and call GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to try and tackle this from a completely different perspective. Memory trouble on Android = the damn native heap and bitmaps 90% of the time.. But this doesn't add up here. As far as I recall, the native heap has very little limitations and can grow as much as it wants. The only limitation I recall is a manual test in the dalvik GC that makes sure your **used** dalvik heap plus your **used** native heap don't surpass your app heap limit.

What if your troubles are not related to the native heap - only your dalvik heap.

I assumed that your failing 500kb allocation is in the native heap (for the bitmap pixels). There's a chance this allocation is actually in your dalvik heap. Since your heap is so fragmented, the system cannot find a continuous 500kb chunk in your dalvik heap and you crash.

Which bitmap decoding function are you using? Some methods decode directly from a resource to the native heap and some methods (like the ones using a byte array), are decoding from buffers on the dalvik heap which would explain a big allocation there.

To fix this either change your bitmap decoding function and make sure it doesn't allocate on the dalvik heap at all, or better yet, let's fix your entire fragmentation problem at the source.

Here are some ideas to work around fragmentation issues in general (apply these during your JSON handling part in the beginning):

1. Run `System.gc()` manually in strategically placed locations. Popular locations are during destruction of large objects like activity onDestroy. Or whenever you finish with a large JSON chunk, throw a manual GC in there.
2. Assist the System GC free resources faster. This will prevent your heap from becoming fragmented in the first place. Plenty of material on the net on how to do that. Some from the top of my head:

   - If you have frequent small allocations, try to adopt a memory reuse scheme like making a pool of objects, and reusing objects in the pool instead of allocating new ones. This optimization is often seen in android adapters (like view reuse in listviews)
   - Manually set variables to null when you don't need them in order to explicitly disconnect them from the reference graph and mark them for easy GC (same goes for explicitly clearing data collections)
   - Avoid immutable classes when you have plenty of operations, like concatenation of strings, use `StringBuilder` instead of regular `String`s
   - Avoid finalizers completely
   - Avoid circular references, or at least change one of them to a weak reference
   - Use weak references in general where they're needed

You can measure how successful you are by making sure your heap does not grow to huge sizes when you're only using a small part of it

Comment: Sprinkling out System.gc() calls doesn't seem to have an impact. I'm using BitmapFactory.decodeStream in this case but there are also failures in other areas where BitmapFactory.decodeResource is used. I added more log output to the question above

Comment: If we want to tackle the fragmentation during the JSON part, please give more info about how you're parsing the JSON (which library/function), how much JSON is it, one huge JSON object or many smaller ones, etc

Comment: I'm parsing the JSON using Jackson + Databinding to read a gzipped InputStream from an HTTP request. It's a lot of smaller objects.

Comment: Are you using streaming or tree model? Do you need all the data in the JSON or only a small part is interesting? Are you using POJO or JsonNode?

Comment: I'm using POJO + tree model. Trying to reserve memory by allocating an empty bitmap (reserving external) or by allocating an empty byte array (reserving dalvik) didn't help. I don't think there is much I can do for these devices asides using the streaming parser and give up on databinding which is incredibly frustrating as iOS or ICS+ devices have no issues parsing this amount of data at all (even the same phone hardware running GB vs. ICS). I'll accept your answer nonetheless. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I'm very interested in your memory issues because I have serious memory issues myself. I haven't done much QA on old devices and I hoped that my strategies work on them. If you want you can publish your JSON code and I'll try to help you reduce the fragmentation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you running on the emulator? Because your heap size seems a bit too small. From my calculation you're crashing after about a total of 11MB total use (dalvik+native) and that's very little. Just to verify, do you have a line similar to this after your crash?

```
08-22 18:16:24.209: I/dalvikvm-heap(471): Clamp target GC heap from 24.610MB to 24.000MB
```

The max heap size (dalvik+native) is different between devices. The minimum is 16MB and the larger your screen resolution, the larger it is. Devices of 480x800 normally have above 32MB. You can control the heap size in your AVD settings of the emulator, make sure it's big enough to reflect a real device.

Regarding your question, you're not supposed to defray the heap yourself. The VM does that automatically. It is true that the whole native heap mess makes it harder for the GC to estimate problems so you'll get a few OutOfMemoryErrors which you can probably avoid by manually running the GC before large allocations.

More specifically, your large allocations happen when bitmaps are parsed (during calls like `BitmapFactory.decodeXXX()`). From my experience it actually helps to run `System.gc()` before them. You only need to do this on pre Honeycomb devices.

Another tip is to free the native allocations as soon as possible. The pixels of your bitmaps are found in the native heap. They are freed only on the bitmaps finalizer, which as you know takes ages to run. This memory will only be freed after several runs of the system GC. This is why it's recommended to free it yourself manually. As soon as you're done with any bitmap, call `Bitmap.recycle()` to free its native memory immediately.

Comment: I'm running on real 2.3 devices (e.g. Droid 2) so raising heap size isn't an option. All bitmap loads are wrapped with try/catch(OOM) and in the catch I call System.gc() and try again. But that doesn't seem to do anything. Unfortunately the VM doesn't defrag the heap automatically and shrinks it appropriately. That's why the native heap never gets enough memory because the Dalvik heap eats up all the resources on startup. This dual heap solution is incredibly frustrating I don't understand why this was implemented this way to begin with

Comment: Instead of try catch and only on OOM do GC, on 2.x devices I always (!) do a GC before any bitmap decode. Try this please. Performance comes 2nd to crashes.. and if later we will want to reduce the number of GC we can check for low memory conditions manually by query of free heap size

Comment: Working on real devices, really?? Help we understand the thing that's not adding up then. The numbers in your log don't add up, the problem I've always experienced was with the actual heap usage (the first number of the pair) not total heap size (the second). Can you provide the full log of the crash including the CLAMP line? We'll get to the bottom of this